# Java equivalent of the VB Request.InputStream

Tags: java, vb.net, web-services

I have a web service that I am re-writing from VB to a Java servlet.  In the web service, I want to extract the body entity set on the client-side as such:

```
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(xml, HTTP.UTF_8);
stringEntity.setContentType("application/xml");
httppost.setEntity(stringEntity);
```

In the VB web service, I get this data by using:

```
Dim objReader As System.IO.StreamReader
objReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream)
Dim strXML As String = objReader.ReadToEnd
```

and this works great.  But I am looking for the equivalent in Java.

I have tried this:

```
ServletInputStream dataStream = req.getInputStream();
byte[] data = new byte[dataStream.toString().length()];
dataStream.read(data);
```

but all it gets me is an unintelligible string:

```
data = [B@68514fec
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a ByteArrayOutputStream, like this:

```
ServletInputStream dataStream = req.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int r;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];

while ((r = dataStream.read(data, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
   baos.write(buffer, 0, r);
} 

baos.flush();

byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Still getting the similar result with this method: data = [B@3ffa7dd2

Comment: `String s = new String(data, "UTF-8");` if the character encoding is UTF-8 as in normal XML. The `.toString()` will give an object representation which often is an Object address like @3ffa7dd2, "[B" for byte arrays.

Comment: Thanks @Joop Eggen that was the missing piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing with printing of java arrays. When you print any java object it is transformed to its string representation by implicit invocation of `toString()` method. Array is an object too and its `toString()` implementation is not too user friendly: it creates string that contains `[`, then symbolic type definition (`B` for `byte` in your case, then the internal reference to the array.

If you want to print the array content use `Arrays.toString(yourArray)`. This static method creates user-friendly string representation of array. This is what you need here.

And yet another note. You do not read your array correctly. Please take a look on @Petter`s answer (+1) - you have to implement a loop to read all bytes from the stream.

Comment: I copied @Petters code verbatim, then renamed the second data byte array to data2 to remove conflict, but still get the same result as I mentioned in my comment.  In other words, I looped.